# Is there a way to have a scrollable list that is editable?

Tags: vba, excel

Following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2zXc9mJX_U) I have a spreadsheet that has a "Edit History" box on it that scrolls up and down. It uses a forms control scroll box and a list on a secondary sheet to create a scrollable list. The problem with this is that you cannot then edit the information in the scroll box (you must edit it on the secondary sheet).

I have VBA that automatically enters the person's name into the scrollbox when they edit any part of the sheet, and then enters "Note:" below that. I want the person to be able to edit the "Note:" box so that they can enter the reason they are editing the sheet:

[image: Edit History Box]

John Smith and James Appleseed are previous users of this sheet. When Wayne Smith comes in to edit the sheet, as soon as he makes a change, it adds "Wayne Smith" and "Note:" to the sheet. (I already have this part working using VBA).

Because of the way that the scroll able list is implemented, it is actually all just formulas within this edit history box. If I double click "Note:" to try and edit it, this is what appears:

[image: Edit List - Unwanted Formula]

But what I want to happen is the ability to edit the "Note:" box (without having to switch to the secondary sheet where the list is actually stored). Essentially I want to make a scroll able text box that is also directly editable, and works with VBA.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. But the formulas would be gone completely. With VBA code you could emulate the exact behavior seen from the formulas... namely extract the appropriate data from the source sheet and display it in your *box* in response to the scrolling of your scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a working example of how to do this.

You can download the workbook [here](http://www.excelhero.com/samples/updateable_listbox_excelhero.xlsm).

This method uses two sheets in a workbook... `Sheet1` for the listbox and `listboxdata` for the data. Sheet1 can be called anything you like.

It would probably be wise to hide the `listboxdata` sheet.

On Sheet1 you need a Forms Control scrollbar. Use the Name Box to rename it: `ScrollBar1`. Assign to it the Scroll() procedure.

All of the code for this app should be placed in the Sheet1 code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const LISTBOX_SCROLLBAR = "scrollbar1"
Private Const LISTBOX_DATASHEET = "listboxdata"
Private Const LISTBOX_DATAHEADR = "a1"
Private Const LISTBOX_SCROLLMAX = 50
Private Const LISTBOX_SCROLLMIN = 1

Private Sub Scroll()
    Dim ListBoxRows&, n&, ndx&, v
    On Error Resume Next
    With Shapes(LISTBOX_SCROLLBAR)
        SetProps ndx
        ListBoxRows = .BottomRightCell.Row - .TopLeftCell.Row
        v = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(LISTBOX_DATASHEET).Range(LISTBOX_DATAHEADR).Resize(ListBoxRows).Offset(ndx)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .TopLeftCell(, 0).Resize(ListBoxRows) = v
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Update(Target As Range)
    With Shapes(LISTBOX_SCROLLBAR)
        If Target.Column = .TopLeftCell(, 0).Column Then
            If Target.Row >= .TopLeftCell.Row And Target.Row <= .BottomRightCell.Row Then
                If Target.Count = 1 Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(LISTBOX_DATASHEET).Range(LISTBOX_DATAHEADR).Offset(.ControlFormat.Value + Target.Row - .TopLeftCell.Row) = Target
                Else
                    Scroll
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub SetProps(Optional ndx&)
    With Shapes(LISTBOX_SCROLLBAR).ControlFormat
        .Min = LISTBOX_SCROLLMIN
        .Max = LISTBOX_SCROLLMAX
        ndx = .Value
    End With
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Update Target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    SetProps
End Sub
```

That's it.

No formulas required in the listbox and any changes made to the cells in the listbox will be written to the source data and kept.

Comment: Works perfectly! Exactly what I wanted and this is an easy and functional solution. Thanks so much.